# Only on device with IOS13 I can't get the unique userid of OneSignal

Tags: swift, xcode, onesignal, ios13, swift5

In the older version with this function it work OneSignal.getPermissionSubscriptionState().subscriptionStatus.userId

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check this: https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-iOS-SDK/issues/504. For now, it doesn't work but maybe they will fix this. :)

Comment: I migrate my pod to this PR pod 'OneSignal', '2.10.1' and it's work well :)